# Not Bitcoin-qt at Software repository 20.04

Tags: bitcoin

Even I've got Bitcoin-qt when I was running Ubuntu 18.04, is not anymore at Ubuntu 20.04

Does anyone knows why disappeared it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Brief search on https://packages.ubuntu.com shows that it was never available via official packages.

But LaunchPad has [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~luke-jr/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoincore) with this package, you can add it and install package with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:luke-jr/bitcoincore
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```